# "setViewControllers" method of UIPageViewController causing a CPU overload in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, cpu-usage, uipageviewcontroller

I have this code snippet in a view controller that conforms to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSMutableArray *tempViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   [tempViewControllers addObject:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page1Controller"]];
   [tempViewControllers addObject:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page2Controller"]];
   [tempViewControllers addObject:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page3Controller"]];
   [tempViewControllers addObject:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page4Controller"]];
   [tempViewControllers addObject:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page5Controller"]];
   self.pages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempViewControllers];

   self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageViewController"];
   self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

   Page1ViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
   NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
   [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

   // Change the size of page view controller
   self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height);

   [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
   [self.containerView addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
   [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.headerView];
}
```

This is working when I run the app in `iOS 8` and in `iOS 9`, but when I run it in `iOS 7`, I see in Xcode that the CPU reaches around 93% of workload, and the app gets blocked and unresponsive.

If I comment the call to `[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];` the app runs normally (but I need such call)...

What could be happening here?

Comment: Maybe you have a layout loop.